# Adding inline image in gmail shows up as attachment

Tags: google-apps-script, html-email

I am trying to add a header image in the emails sent in apps script.  In my apps script I have the following:

```
let image = DriveApp.getFileById("10iAyjrAeTBOBTuqGmAv_SmbuUvhR8NYL").getAs("image/png");
let logo = {"logo":image};
```

and in the template file the following:

```
<img src="cid.logo" alt="The Logo">
```

But when the email is sent, it just shows The Logo, and it has the png file referenced as an attachment. It shows at bottom as Logo.png size unknown.

So if I click the attachment it opens with the correct image from my drive, so that isn't the issue.  What other reason am I missing that it is not displaying inline in the email?
Thanks,
Doc

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I have tried changing `src="cid.logo"` to `src="cid:logo"` and it works on my end. Please let me know if this resolves your issue.

Comment: Cooper, was just about to give you a minimal example when I read Georges comment.  That solved it.  Just not seeing the period instead of the colon.  I new it was something simple I was just not seeing!  Thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad it worked, let me compose it as an answer. By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

### Issue:

The behaviour you have encountered was due to the syntax in image source call in your html file.

Try the modification below

### From this:

```
<img src="cid.logo" alt="The Logo">
```

### To this:

```
<img src="cid:logo" alt="The Logo">
```

### Reference:

[Class MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailmessage)

Comment: Hello @Doc I am glad that your issue was resolved by my comment. Feel free to accept my answer by clicking the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me.  [how to accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1):

This is an example that create the imgobj and assigns it to the inlineimages advanced parameter

the html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Email Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <img src="cid:img0" style="margin:2px 5px 2px 0;" /><?= filename[0] ?><br />
     <img src="cid:img1" style="margin:2px 5px 2px 0;" /><?= filename[1] ?><br />
     <? for(var i = 0;i < values.length; i++) { ?>
        <br /><?= "Data" + Number( i + 1) + ': ' + values[i] ?>
     <? } ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

The gs:

```
function sendEmails101(obj) {
  let imgObj = {};
  let fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderid");
  let files = fldr.getFilesByType(MimeType.JPEG);
  let n = 0;
  let names = ['die1.jpg', 'die2.jpg'];
  let filename = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    let f = files.next();
    let index = names.indexOf(f.getName());
    if (~index) {
      imgObj[`img${n++}`] = f.getBlob();
      filename.push(names[index]);
    }
  }
  let htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(obj.row[obj.index['htmlFile']]);
  htmlTemplate.values = obj.row.slice(obj.index['Data0']);
  htmlTemplate.filename = filename;
  let html = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
  if (html) {
    if (obj.row[obj.index['operation']] == 'Create Draft') {
      GmailApp.createDraft(obj.row[obj.index['Recipients']], obj.row[obj.index['Subject']], '', { htmlBody: html, inlineImages: imgObj, replyTo: obj.row[obj.index['replyTo']] });
    } else {

      GmailApp.sendEmail(obj.row[obj.index['Recipients']], obj.row[obj.index['Subject']], '', { htmlBody: html, inlineImages: imgObj, replyTo: obj.row[obj.index['replyTo']] });
    }
  }
```

}